# Is boost::lexical_cast thread-safe?

Tags: c++, boost, thread-safety, atof, lexical-cast

I am actually failing to find an answer to this question in boost documentation. I am being a bit paranoid about using `atof` in a multi-threaded environment, so one suggestion was to replace the call with `lexical_cast`. Is `lexical_cast` thread-safe?

Comment: Out of interest, why are you paranoid about the thread safety/re-entrancy of atof? I can't think of any reason to use static storage, or any interaction with global state except the locale. Is it that?

Comment: yes, `setlocale` problem

Comment: atof and sprintf are generally not suitable for production code, as they are prone to breakage on `.` versus `,`.  This is rather unfortunate as it's hard to write these yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concurrent calls to `lexical_cast` are safe. But pay attention that it depends on (at least for my installed version of Boost) the currently installed C++ locale. Access to the installed C++ (as well as C) locale should be synchronized manually by the user. See the **Data races** section [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/locale/global/). So, for example, concurrent calls to `lexical_cast` and `std::locale::global` are unsafe. Despite this, it is considered bad practice to change the installed C/C++ locale other than at program startup.

Comment: Aha! Interesting, so actually my worries about `atof` aren't going to be solved by `lexical_cast`. :) Thank you.

Comment: Better implement your own. Few format-related facilities in the standard library are independent of the global C or C++ locale.

Comment: Not only standard library, boost as well, even spirit uses locale - hard to avoid really...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `boost::lexical_cast` does not modify the input string in any way and produces a new output if run on the same string from multiple threads.

It creates a `stringstream` which in itself is not thread-safe, i.e. cannot be shared between threads without synchronisation, but would use a different `stringstream` object in each thread.

The issue I have with `lexical_cast` which is why I avoid using it is the total uselessness of the exception it throws (bad_cast with no context). However that is a separate issue, not thread-safety.

Another issue (limitation) with lexical_cast is that it will only use the C locale (classic). So if you have your own facet, maybe for date-times, and you want to use lexical_cast on it, you may be tempted to modify the classic locale as a workaround, and that is where it will stop being thread-safe unless it is done right at the start.

In reality, if you are parsing a file you would probably be better off using either `boost::spirit` if it has a specific grammar or `boost::serialize` or even regular istream. In fact `boost::lexical_cast` would be highly inefficient for this purpose as it creates a new stream for every token.

Comment: Boost has had [try_lexical_convert](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/synopsis.html#boost_lexical_cast.synopsis.try_lexical_convert) since 1.56

Comment: I don't mind it throwing, but the exception text should include the symbol being converted and the type to which you were trying to convert it.

A good "wrapper" though, that might use try_lexical_convert would pass in file and line (not __FILE__ and __LINE__ but the filename or stream name being parsed and the line number in that stream) and would output that too in the error message.

Comment: Interestingly, how would you include the value in a message if conversion to string failed? Also, streams have no line number information, generically. So the things you mention are GoodThings but arguably reasonably absent from a library this generic. Boost Lexicalcast is a building block IMO

Comment: I'm not sure how conversion to string can fail at run-time. Either a value has a stream overload or not. Normally one wouldn't not implement operator<< to leave a fail state.

Comment: Fair enough. <padding/>